# Cypress - how to have one code for every test case

Tags: javascript, testing, package, automated-tests, cypress

Is in Cypress some sort of packages how can I have only one code for every test case I'm making?

For example: I have one same process of clicking through my website but I need to have like 20 test cases. This website is still upgrading so if there will be change of site I don't want to make changes in code for every test case but only on one place.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please show some code as an example. Obviously some code is easy to extract to a common function and some is hard. One way is [Cypress custom commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html) and you can also use plain JS functions, but it depends on what your code looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a common `login` I have added in commands.js file. In my test requirement, for every test suite I need to have a `login()` function to be called. Here I am calling the login() inside the `before({})` tag which runs once before all tests in the block. I guess, similar way you can add `click through my website`, but need to understand the flow of your program in more detail.

/integration/examples

Test suite and tests

```
describe('Some name of the test suite', function(){
  before('Before the test clear previous Cookies', () => {
    cy.wait(2000)
    cy.clearCookies()
    cy.login(Cypress.env('username'), Cypress.env('password'))

  });

  /* Test case 1*/

  it('Name of first test case', function(){
     // test steps to add 
   })      

  /* Test case 2*/

  it('Name of second test case', function () {
     // test steps to add 
   })

})
```

/support/commands.js file

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (username, password) => {
   cy.visit('/')
   cy.get("#Loginuser").type(username)
   cy.get("#Loginpass").type(password, {log:false})
   cy.get("button[type='submit']").contains("Login").click()
});
```